# Swift error when trying to use the Firestore API

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am tying to update a database field in the `firestore` db and every time I call a function the app errors out with:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is the function: (*note that this function is under where the button is being called in the full code*)

```
private func updateDocument() {
    // [START update_document]
    let testingDataChange = db.collection("homeBase").document("78kBh2c2OeNN8aTazMmz")

    // Set the "capital" field of the city 'DC'
    testingDataChange.updateData([
        "armMove": true
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error updating document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully updated")
        }
    }
    // [END update_document]
}
```

I am calling it here when a button is clicked

```
@IBAction func loginTap(_ sender: Any) {
    updateDocument()
}
```

As soon as the button is clicked the error happens and the app stops.

Answer (score 0):

You firestore code is fine. The problem is in swift code. Try right click the button from storyboard, disconnect it from the code and reconnect it.